# How to retrieve uploaded picture data in relation to Webapi

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Goal:
Upload a picture and then save it to the path "C:\test\"

Problem:
The main problem is that HOW should .net core code be constructed that the code shoud retrieve the incoming data (post data that is picture) and then save it in the local computer.

I don't know where to start.

Info:
*Angular and c.net core is separated and they are not in the same solution.
VS code is used for Angular and VS 2017 for .net core.
*The frontend code is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o1asqg
The source code is "https://w3path.com/new-angular-8-file-upload-or-image-upload/"

Thank you!

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem you're facing?  The code you posted doesn't show any attempt to upload an image.... it looks like the default template for a WebAPI controller.

Comment: "I don't know where to start." I need to see a sample or similar in order to continue working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main problem is that HOW should .net core code be constructed that the code shoud retrieve the incoming data (post data that is picture) and then save it in the local computer.

You could receive `IFormFile files`on web api POST action parameters, the name `files` correspond to the key name to your angular `formData`. if you need to append other properties to angular `formData`, you could receive a view model contains all those properties on  asp.net core action.

A simple working demo is shown below.

Angular:

```
onSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', this.fileData);

    this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/values/addfile', formData)
      .subscribe(events => {        
        alert('SUCCESS !!');
  }) 
}
```

Asp.Net Core web api:

```
[HttpPost("addFile")]
public async Task AddFile(IFormFile files)
    {

        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
        var filePath = Path.Combine("C:\\test", fileName);

        using (var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await files.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
        }         

    }
```